# How to have vba paste into a cell that contains a formula

Tags: vba, excel

I apologise if this has been answered in a previous thread, I search for a while but was really unsure of what to call the problem I am having.

I am very new to VBA, this is my first real foray into it.

I am having an issue with VBA pasting the contents of a form into a spreadsheet to the spreadsheet having a vlookup reference column in column one (the sheet requires to have a excel lookup of the form so this reference is required)

I am currently using a button with:-

```
Private Sub submit_Click()
Dim RowCount As Long
RowCount = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Private Sub submit_Click()

With Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B1")
.Offset(RowCount, 0).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy")
.Offset(RowCount, 1).Value = Me.operator.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 2).Value = Me.custexp.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 3).Value = Me.fcr.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 4).Value = Me.opfcr.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 5).Value = Me.compliant.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 6).Value = Me.summary.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 7).Value = Me.evaluation.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 8).Value = Me.compliance.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 9).Value = Me.callid.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 10).Value = Me.calltime.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 11).Value = Me.leader.Value
.Offset(RowCount, 12).Value = Me.custnum.Value
End With

Dim ctl As Control

End Sub
```

But this finds the first completely blank cell and avoids anything with formula in it.

Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: You need to show more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
Private Sub submit_Click()
    Dim c As Range
    'find first empty cell in ColB (looking from the bottom of the sheet)
    Set c = Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

    With c.EntireRow
        .Cells(2).Value = Format(Now, "dd/mm/yyyy")
        .Cells(3).Value = Me.Operator.Value
        .Cells(4).Value = Me.custexp.Value
        .Cells(5).Value = Me.fcr.Value
        .Cells(6).Value = Me.opfcr.Value
        .Cells(7).Value = Me.compliant.Value
        .Cells(8).Value = Me.Summary.Value
        .Cells(9).Value = Me.evaluation.Value
        .Cells(10).Value = Me.compliance.Value
        .Cells(11).Value = Me.callid.Value
        .Cells(12).Value = Me.calltime.Value
        .Cells(13).Value = Me.leader.Value
        .Cells(14).Value = Me.custnum.Value
    End With

End Sub
```